# First Prize: Wisdom of 1972

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, language

[image: First Prize: Wisdom of 1972]

Clues: [contextual images]

Q: Lei parla inglese?
A: ♂

[25 puzzle pieces with letters inside]

[I] [S] [N] [U] [P]
[N] [R] [I] [S] [N]
[C] [I] [S] [N] [I]
[I] [E] [O] [C] [L]
[L] [E] [O] [C] [L]

Instructions: Name That Artist
_ _ _ _ A _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ A _ _

Hint:

> The Sun finishes the sequence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The artist is:

> Adriano Celentano!

> The first clue obviously was to translate the question to English, where I learned that it is asked in Italian, meaning "Do you speak English?" The answer is the symbol for male, which, also in Italian, means "Badly". It was interesting that it wasn't written out but rather symbolically answered, indicating that our person of interest is likely Italian and known for bad English. Using some search engine power, I discovered Adriano Celentano, who wrote a song called Prisencolinensinainciusol (released in November 1972), which is 25 letters long and spellable with the puzzle pieces! The clue tying the song to the question is that the song is gibberish; the lyrics don't mean anything and was meant to mimic how English sounds to Non-English speakers, hence the answer being symbolic. The given hint is hinting at the last three letters being Sol, which is Sun in Spanish.

OP Edit:

> The first part of the tile is a hint. "First Prize" points to the top row of puzzle pieces to be "PRISE". Then rearrange the pieces containing the letter "I" to the spots marked with an eye symbol.

> Also, the word "wisdom" in the title is a joke, because the song is 100% gibberish.

Comment: Do the jigsaw pieces fit together somehow to form the answer? And what do the eyes on some pieces signify?

Comment: I'm still playing with the pieces. I ordered them to spell out the song title, including swapping some of the repeating letters, and haven't come across anything significant yet.